# How to display all row in database - Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have simple issue with my Laravel application.But i can not find any solution of it.Please see my code here:

**controller:**

```
public function index(){
    $members = Member::paginate(15);

    $meal_entry = Member::all();
    $breakfast = DB::SELECT("SELECT self_meal_breakfast + guest_meal_breakfast AS breakfast FROM meal_entry");
    $lunch = DB::SELECT("SELECT self_meal_lunch + guest_meal_lunch AS lunch FROM meal_entry");        
    $dinner = DB::SELECT("SELECT self_meal_dinner + guest_meal_dinner AS dinner FROM meal_entry");
    $total_meal = DB::SELECT("SELECT self_meal_breakfast + self_meal_lunch + self_meal_dinner + guest_meal_breakfast + guest_meal_lunch + guest_meal_dinner AS total FROM meal_entry");

    return view('member.mealView', compact('members','data','breakfast','lunch','dinner','meal_entry','total_meal'));
}
```

**blade view:**

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        @foreach($meal_entry as $value)
        <td>{{ $value->created_at }}</td>
        @endforeach                                        
        @foreach($breakfast as $value)
        <td>{{ $value->breakfast }}</td>
        @endforeach                                        
        @foreach($lunch as $value)
        <td>{{ $value->lunch }}</td>
        @endforeach                                        
        @foreach($dinner as $value)
        <td>{{ $value->dinner }}</td>
        @endforeach                                        
        @foreach($total_meal as $value)
        <td>{{ $value->total }}</td>
        @endforeach                                        
        @foreach($meal_entry as $value)
        <td>{{ $value->created_at }}</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And the table: **[meal_entry](http://prnt.sc/d7whid)**.

If there is a one `row` in the database then its ok ( **[see](http://prntscr.com/d7wbsu)** ) to view.But when there is `row` more than one then its show in one `row` with all data( **[see](http://prntscr.com/d7wb9s)** ).How can i handle this things? I think it should be run another loop but how can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please, could you show us how would be the table looks like?
Thanks!

Comment: @IdirOuhabMeskine of course... http://prntscr.com/d7whid

Comment: Since the data are in one table. You should perform single query.

Comment: @KinshukLahiri How can i do that with single query? Because i have some arithmetic calculation in different.Could you show me?

Comment: Instead of this four queries breakfast etc. you should have only one, and then loop in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if you're using Laravel, one of the best features that has is the accessors:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

You can create new attributes and use them as model attributes.

For some stuff are very useful.

```
class Meal extends Model
{
    public function getTotalBreakfastAttribute()
    {
        return $this->self_meal_breakfast + $this->guest_meal_breakfast;
    }
}
```

And then, use this accessor as attribute:

```
<tbody>
   @foreach($foods as $value)
    <tr>
       <td> {{$value->total_breakfast}} </td> 
       <td> {{$value->created_at}} </td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Or if you don't want to do that, instead of use multiple queries to get the data, just use one because all the fields are in the same table, and then, you could use the above example.

Enjoy! :)

Comment: Yes this is thing what i looking for.A+++

Answer (score 0):

A quick patch would be to do only one query and then do the calculations on the view (I know that is not a good practice to do the calculations in the view, but is the easiest way that i can see).

It would be like this:

**Controller:**

```
public function index(){
    $members = Member::paginate(15);

    return view('member.mealView', compact('members'));
}
```

**blade view**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($members as $meal_entry)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $meal_entry->created_at }}</td>

        <td>{{ $breakfast = $meal_entry->self_meal_breakfast + $meal_entry->guest_meal_breakfast }}</td>

        <td>{{ $lunch = $meal_entry->self_meal_lunch+ $meal_entry->guest_meal_lunch}}</td>

        <td>{{ $dinner = $meal_entry->self_meal_dinner + $meal_entry->guest_meal_dinner }}</td>

        <td>{{ $breakfast + $lunch + $dinner }}</td>

        <td>{{ $meal_entry->created_at }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach 
</tbody>
```

And remember to add

```
{{ $members->links() }}
```

Where you want the pagination links.